# CGI on Python(Mac OS)

Tags: python, macos, cgi

I set CGi in Python project. In MAC OS i got this error, when i ran this project. In Windows this project had worked. What is the problem ? I created server

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()`
```

and in folder cgi-bin created hello.py

```
print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<h1>Hello world!</h1>")
```

I read that i can use `chmod a+x hello.py`, but i need to run this script in browser

Error:

```
Error response 
Error code 403
Messsage: cgi-script is not executable (‘cgi/bin/hello.py’)
Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN - Request forbidden — authorization will not help
```

Comment: the script itself needs execute permissions.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include exactly how you invoke your script and the exact error you got, in full.

Comment: Edit question: add error

Comment: Why `chmod +x cgi/bin/hello.py` does not work? What error messages it prints?

Comment: Try putting a shebang at the start of your Python script so the kernel knows it's Python `#!/usr/bin/env python3` There's a space between `env` and `python3`

Comment: How can I run in BROWSER , this command run project in terminal